# Apache2 Proxy SSL Cert Check

Tags: ssl, apache2

Let's have a webserver with a valid TLS cert called b.my.tld.

I want to configure apache2 on a.my.tld as reverse proxy for b.my.tld. So I added

```
ProxyPass / https://b.my.tld/
ProxyPassReverse / https://b.my.tld/
```

My problem is: apache2 on server a does not connect to b.my.tld because it expects the TLS certificate for a.my.tld - and not for b.

Is there any possibility to configure apache2 to accept a certificate for a specific hostname - or for the hostname defined in ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `https://b.my.tld/` and apache expects a.my.tld it is because you are probably using `ProxyPreserveHost on` somewhere else, thing that you don't mention. Otherwise it will expect a certificate for b.my.tld.

Anyways, ideally hosts you reverse proxy to should have a certificate matching their hostname (nowadays thanks to Google idiosyncrasy, a DNS, and not a CN entry, should be sufficient.) But for those cases when you need to make an exception, for this and cases where you use `ProxyPreserveHost on`, Apache HTTPD can just ignore the destination certificate name with:

```
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
```

Answer (score -1):

To configure Apache2 as a reverse proxy for a different domain with its own TLS certificate (b.my.tld in your case), you'll need to use the `SSLProxyEngine` directive and configure a virtual host specifically for the reverse proxy. Here's how you can do it:

1. Make sure the `proxy` and `proxy_http` modules are enabled in Apache:

```bash
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

2. Create a new virtual host configuration file for a.my.tld:

```bash
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/a.my.tld.conf
```

3. In the virtual host configuration file, set up the reverse proxy and specify the TLS settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName a.my.tld
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/a.my.tld.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/a.my.tld.key
    
    ProxyPass / https://b.my.tld/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://b.my.tld/
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure to replace `/path/to/a.my.tld.crt` and `/path/to/a.my.tld.key` with the actual paths to the SSL certificate and private key files for a.my.tld.

4. Enable the new virtual host and reload Apache:

```bash
sudo a2ensite a.my.tld.conf
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Now, Apache on server a will act as a reverse proxy for b.my.tld, and it will use the SSL certificate specified for a.my.tld when communicating with b.my.tld. This configuration allows you to handle SSL termination at the reverse proxy level while serving content from the backend server (b.my.tld) securely.